# foreach loop to cycle though an array of dates to to be displayed in separate tables

Tags: php, html

I am trying to structure my foreach loop to cycle though all the dates in my time stamp arrays so that I can display the results in 5 separate tables for each of the dates

This my function to get the information from the database

```
$users_site = "London";

$timeStampFrom = ( [0] => 1596655740 [1] => 1596745740 [2] => 1596828540 [3] => 1597087740 [4] => 1597177800 );

$timeStampTo = ( [0] => 1596659340 [1] => 1596749340 [2] => 1596832140 [3] => 1597095000 [4] => 1597181400 );

function show_available_equipment($users_site, $timeStampFrom, $timeStampTo){
// defines db from instialize page as a global variable
foreach ($timeStampFrom as $timeStampStart=>$timeStampTo) {

global $db;
//SQL statement to query the database for available gear
$sql= "SELECT av_inventory.ID AS equipID, av_equipment_type.equipment, "
        . "av_inventory.product, av_inventory.serial, av_inventory.current_location, "
        . "av_inventory.site, av_inventory.status, av_products.product, av_buildings.building FROM av_inventory JOIN "
        . "av_equipment_type ON av_inventory.equipment =av_equipment_type.ID "
        . "JOIN av_products ON av_inventory.product = av_products.ID JOIN "
        . "av_buildings ON av_inventory.current_location = av_buildings.ID WHERE "
        . "av_inventory.site =?  AND av_inventory.ID NOT IN (SELECT av_bookings.av_inventory_id FROM "
        . "av_bookings WHERE date_time_from <= ? and date_time_to >= ?)  GROUP BY av_inventory.ID;";


        // prepares our sql statement
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db);
        //if there is a SQL error exit
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: book_gear.php?error=sqlerror123");
         exit();
         }
        // otherwise go ahead
        else {
        /* binding those variables to the question marks in SQl statement
         * above variables need to be prepared and binded like this in php
         * and cannot just be inserted into statements
         */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $users_site, $timeStampStart, $timeStampTo);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        return $result;
}}}
```

Here I try and display the information based on the 5 dates given.
One table for each day.
At the moment I just get information for the first day which makes me think my function loop is incorrect.

```
<?php $equipments[] = book_equip_idle($users_site, $timeStampFrom, $timeStampTo); ?>

<?php foreach ($equipments as $equipment) { ;?>

    <table id="schedule_table_new" class="schedule_list">
      <tr>
      <caption class="sched_label">Event Name</caption>
      <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Equipment Type</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Product No.</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Serial No.</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(3)">Current Location</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(5)">Book Item</th>
  </tr>
  <br/><br/>



  <?php
    while ($av_inventory = mysqli_fetch_assoc($equipment)) { ?>



      <tr>
      <td><?php echo h($av_inventory['equipment']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo h($av_inventory['product']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo h($av_inventory['serial']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo h($av_inventory['building']); ?></td>
      <!--Checkbox sends two pieces of data equipment name to events SQL
      table and serial number to bookings SQL table -->
      <td><input name='event[<?php echo $key ;?>][equipment][]' type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $av_inventory['equipID'];?>"></td>
     </tr>
  <?php } } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function that gets the SQL data, the results is returned after the first loop:

```
function show_available_equipment($users_site, $timeStampFrom, $timeStampTo){
      // defines db from instialize page as a global variable
      foreach ($timeStampFrom as $timeStampStart=>$timeStampTo) { // <----- Only runs once

            ........................

            //if there is a SQL error exit
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                header("Location: book_gear.php?error=sqlerror123");
                exit();
             }
            // otherwise go ahead
            else {
                
                ...........................

                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                return $result; //  <---------- Returns after first loop
            }
      }
}
```

After each result in retrieved from the database, you need to add it to some sort of `$all_results` variable. When the loop is complete, return `$all_results`.